# ABP Application Service Post With Request Body

Tags: c#, abp

I need to create an application service which has a post methd, In this method the logic needs to access the request body in order to work with it, is it possible to do this inside an ABP application service, I have posted an example of another service.

public class MedistatWebHookController : ControllerBase
{

```
    private readonly ILogger<MedistatWebHookController> _logger;

    public MedistatWebHookController(ILogger<MedistatWebHookController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Service Has Started {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Events")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveEvents()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Start logging email post request from events {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")));

            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("Request Body {0}", Request.Body));

            var parser = new WebhookParser();
            var events = await parser.ParseEventsWebhookAsync(Request.Body).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //Event event = new Event();

            foreach(var emailEvent in events)
            {
                var dump = ObjectDumper.Dump(emailEvent);
                // Create a file to write to
                string createText = dump;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Medistat\\Logs\\EmailEvents.txt", createText);
            }


            return Ok(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I dont know how to access the request body inside the application service method. I have read through the documentation and I'm not seeing anything

Answer (score 1):

Since `HttpContext` is part of web layer, it's not true to use it in application layer. But if you still want, add reference to `System.Web` and use `HttpContext.Current` static property.

My advice would be to get the information you want from request on the controller side and pass it as a parameter to `ApplicationService`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to add the system.web reference into my application service but it does not allow adding that reference. When you search for the reference it does not come back in the list. Because the solution is writtein in the ABP framework, the controllers are automatically generated which means I'm not able to pass the request from the controller

Comment: Actually, you can do this. For example, here [EventAppService](1) implements IEventAppService. Also [EventController](2) implements IEventAppService. I believe you will solve the problem by reviewing the Eventhub project. If you have problems, please write.

1. https://github.com/abpframework/eventhub/blob/main/src/EventHub.Application/Events/EventAppService.cs
2. https://github.com/abpframework/eventhub/blob/main/src/EventHub.HttpApi/Controllers/Events/EventController.cs